# How to model an already written object library in UML?

Tags: object, uml

I have to model an already written object library in UML.Now, I've read tutorials and examples, but they only discuss real life examples such as cars and their components or students, professors and classes. Obviously, those are very easy to model in UML. However, the particular thing about this library is that it contains both classes which define different objects and Windows forms that allow the user to interact with them. A form can both represent an object graphically by all kinds of Windows controls and allow the user to modify it. In addition, there's also a sort of 'main class' which uploads and downloads these objects to and from a remote server. Obviously, this 'main class' handles all aspects of communication and acts like a data channel. So, schematically this is how the library looks like:

Object1Class [Field1, Field2, ....]
Object2Class [Field1, Field2, ....]
...

Object1Form
Object2Form
...

MainClass (NB: this class doesn't create any forms. It just uses the objects created by the forms. The forms are used externally by software systems which rely on this library)

So how would I model this using UML?

Thanks in advcance,
AlgolDocks

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the context but it seems to me that a good reverse of the object library could be a good start. You can get class and sequence diagram showing static architecture or methods interactions. You can also revers more than one library which is really useful if you need to understand what is going on.
Having said that I found an example of Jar reverse engineering at: http://www.ejb3.org/jar_file_reverse/jar_file_reverse.html

You should certainly have other tools providing this kind of reverse but I don't know about them providing such an advanced feature therefore can not help further.